# I can't run migration (with .net core 3.0 and entity framework)

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, .net-core-3.0

My .Net Core version is `3.0.100-preview6-012264`. You can ask me why I use the preview version. The main reason is useful work with GRPC (scaffolding for this). Now I would like to use entity framework in my project. I have the following `.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Protobuf Include="Protos\dashboard.proto" GrpcServices="Server" Generator="MSBuild:Compile" />
        <Protobuf Include="Protos\users.proto" GrpcServices="Client" Generator="MSBuild:Compile" />
        <Protobuf Include="Protos\anal.proto" GrpcServices="Client" Generator="MSBuild:Compile" />
        <Content Include="@(Protobuf)" />
        <None Remove="@(Protobuf)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="DimaRabbitLogger" Version="1.3.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore.Server" Version="0.1.22-pre1" />
        <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.8.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="1.21.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
        <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Core" Version="1.21.0" />

        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0-preview6.19304.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.0.0-preview5" />

        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
        <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization.Json" Version="4.3.0" />

    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And couple of very simple models:

Model `Application`:

```
public class Application
{
    int ApplicationId { get; set; }

    public string PackageName { get; set; }

    public List<WorkspaceApplication> WorkspaceApplications { get; set; }
```

Model `Workspace`:

```
public class Workspace
{
    public int WorkspaceId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<WorkspaceApplication> WorkspaceApplications { get; set; }

}
```

Class for many-to-many relationship:

```
public class WorkspaceApplication
{
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public Application Application { get; set; }

    public string WorkspaceId { get; set; }
    public Workspace Workspace { get; set; }
}
```

And my application context:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DbSet<Workspace> Workspaces { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DashboardDb");
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Dashboard"));
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<WorkspaceApplication>()
            .HasKey(x => new {x.WorkspaceId, x.ApplicationId});

        modelBuilder.Entity<WorkspaceApplication>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Workspace)
            .WithMany(x => x.WorkspaceApplications)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.WorkspaceId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<WorkspaceApplication>()
            .HasOne(x => x.Application)
            .WithMany(x => x.WorkspaceApplications)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ApplicationId);
    }
}
```

I run the following console command:

`dotnet ef migrations add FirstMigration`

and have this error message:

> Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
>   Possible cause:
>    * You have incorrectly typed builtin dotnet.
>    * You planned to run .NET Core, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
>    * You wanted to run the global tool, but the PATH specified in the PATH could not find the executable file with the dotnet prefix, which has this name.

This works nice with .Net Core 2.2. Where is the problem?

Comment: do you have a global.json file in your project, pinning the SDK version?

Comment: No. How it can help? Currently, I have two SDK versions (3.0 and 2.2) on my machine. But when I type in the console `dotnet --version` I see this result `3.0.100-preview6-012264`

Comment: Sorry, I read it quickly and thought it was something else. From 3.0 preview 4, you need it as a global dotnet tool. See my answer on how to install/use it .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Starting with 3.0 the `dotnet ef` is not part of the .NET SDK anymore.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#the-ef-core-command-line-tool-dotnet-ef-is-no-longer-part-of-the-net-core-sdk)

> Old behavior
>
> Before 3.0, the dotnet ef tool was included in the .NET Core SDK and was readily available to use from the command line from any project without requiring extra steps.
>
> **New behavior**
>
> Starting in 3.0, the .NET SDK does not include the dotnet ef tool, so before you can use it you have to explicitly install it as a local or global tool.

To install it, you can run this:

`dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 3.0.0-*`

Then you should be able to run normal ef-core commands like `dotnet ef migrations add ...`

Don't forget to add the path to dotnet tools in the `PATH` variable of your OS. For example if you use linux ubuntu and zsh  as shell you have to add the following int your `.zshrc` file:

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.dotnet/tools`

Comment: This command tells me `Tool 'dotnet-ef' is already installed.`. But I don't have this installed globally. Running the migration command gives me error from my question(

Comment: Then it must be installed. Run `dotnet tool list` to list the local installed tools or `dotnet tool list --global` to list the globally installed. Check if `ef` is in any of them. If yes, then you need to uninstall.

Comment: It gives me `dotnet-ef       2.2.4        dotnet-ef`. Is it a conflict with my .net 2.2 SDK? (I have two versions of SDK on my machine 2.2 and 3.0.100-preview6). How to solve this conflict?

Comment: Yes, so that's what I imagined. You have installed the 2.2.* `ef` as a global tool before, but you don't need it since it's part of the SDK. You can just uninstall it `dotnet tool uninstall dotnet-ef --global` and then install the 3.0 again. In case you need to use `dotnet ef` in 2.2 projects, you can just put a `global.json` in the root, and it will use the `ef` tool contained in the 2.2 SDK.

Comment: Ok I have installed this. In my .NET tools global list I have the following `dotnet-ef       3.0.0-preview6.19304.10      dotnet-ef`. But `dotnet ef migrations add <name>` gives me the same( And I have `global.json` with the following content `{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "3.0.100-preview6-012264"
  }
}`. The file is situated in the root of my solution.

Comment: Strange. Maybe try closing the console and opening again? I just created a new project, with the latest 3.0 SDK and packages ` 3.0.0-preview7.19362.6` and it works fine. I also had the `dotnet ef` tool installed and had no issues.

Comment: How many SDKs you have on your local machine? I opened a project where I had used 2.2 SDK (I have global.json for this in the project). And in the terminal, in the root of the solution I have typed `dotnet ef` and it works. The last `dotnet-ef` works for 2.2 SDK.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197614/discussion-between-jpgrassi-and-aleksej-shherbak).

Comment: @jpgrassi - thanks! after installing the tool, closing the console down and opening again seems to have done the trick.